# Truffle test seems to succeed, but then 'transaction wasn't processed in 240 seconds! '

Tags: truffle, truffle-test

I have 5 smart contract functions and 26 unit tests for them. If I run the tests together, they run green, however, in the end, I get a timeout error: [image: timeout]

The error message wasn't quite informative for me, so I started to comment out the tests one by one, and all of my tests seem to be good together until I add a particular one (see below).

The relevant smart contract function:

```
mapping(uint256=>bytes32[]) idRowArrayMapping;

event QueryResultStored(
    uint256 queryId,
    uint256 resultId
);
event RowStored();
event Error(string errorMessage);

enum ViewResultCodes { Success, NoMatchFound, IntegerNotPositive, StringEmpty }
ViewResultCodes public viewResultCode;

function validateRow(uint256 _resultId, string _rowString) external view returns (ViewResultCodes result) {
    if (_resultId <= 0) {
      return ViewResultCodes.IntegerNotPositive;
    }
    if (bytes(_rowString).length == 0) {
      return ViewResultCodes.StringEmpty;
    }

    bytes32 rowHash = keccak256(_rowString);
    bytes32[] storage dataSet = idRowArrayMapping[_resultId];

    for (uint i = 0; i < dataSet.length; i++) {
      if (dataSet[i] == rowHash) {
        return ViewResultCodes.Success;
      }
    }
    return ViewResultCodes.NoMatchFound;
  }
```

And the unit test for it:

```
'use strict';

const QueryResultHandler = artifacts.require("./QueryResultHandler");
const ViewResultCodes = {
  Success: 0,
  NoMatchFound: 1,
  IntegerNotPositive: 2,
  StringEmpty: 3
};

let instance;

contract('validateRow() function test', function() {
  beforeEach('Setup contract for each test', async function() {
    instance = await QueryResultHandler.deployed();
  });

  it("(0,'a'): Should return the StringEmpty code", async () => {
    instance.validateRow.call(0,'a').then(function(viewResultCode) {
      assert.equal(viewResultCode, ViewResultCodes.IntegerNotPositive, "Returned code was: " + viewResultCode);
    });
  })
})
```

Also, if I run the test alone, there is no timeout and it works fine. I would be grateful for any ideas, what can be the problem.

Comment: Mixing promises and async/await can create some problems (I think perhaps your test is finishing before the calls complete). Try `const viewResultCode = await instance.validateRow.call(0,'a');
 assert.equal(viewResultCode, ViewResultCodes.IntegerNotPositive, "Returned code was: " + viewResultCode);`

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot, it worked! Can you please post this as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mixing promises and async/await can create some problems if you are not very careful.

I think your test finishes while the call is still running. To ensure the call completes before the test ends try waiting for the result:

```
it("(0,'a'): Should return the StringEmpty code", async () => {
  const viewResultCode = await instance.validateRow.call(0,'a');
  assert.equal(viewResultCode, ViewResultCodes.IntegerNotPositive, "Returned code was: " + viewResultCode);
});
```